# Pass custom glob to ripgrep when using Telescope live_grep

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope, ripgrep

I want to use the `find_command` argument in Telescope's `live_grep`, as far as I know, it accepts a list of arguments that will be passed to `ripgrep` in this case.

This command works in the terminal:

`rg -g "**/*.spec*" react-redux`

So I want to setup a custom mapping that passes these arguments to live_grep like so:

`x = {":Telescope live_grep find_command=rg,-g,'**/*.spec*'<cr>", "X Grep"},`

However this is not working, it's searching without taking into consideration the glob passed.

Any ideas on how to solve this?